# Referencing silverlight assembly within a XNA project in windows phone mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, certificate, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I am currently working on a silverlight based project, which in pre windows phone mango era, could not be integrated with a XNA project as per the following clause in microsoft certification requirement.

> 4.2.5 The application must not call any APIs in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly or the
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics assembly when using any methods from
>   the System.Windows.Controls namespace.

Starting with mango update, windows phone allows integrating XNA and silverlight code together, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938(v=vs.92).aspx. Although it requires starting from a different project template and using a new class - *UIElementRenderer*, which seems to be based on Silverlight's *UIElement* class. Though i had something different in mind, which is as easy as a single project referencing both Silverlight as well as XNA runtime libraries.

My question is, for windows mango, is it possible for a XNA platform developer to integrate 
with my code(actually an assembly) which makes direct silverlight API calls? If not how easy it is to modify my code to be able to provide a single assembly output,  which can be included in both XNA and silverlight projects.

Thanks for reading so far, any advice/help is much appretiated . :)

**tl;dr: In Windows Phone Mango SDK, Is it allowed to make direct silverlight API calls from within a XNA project, from the app certification requirements perspective?**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Dark Genesis blog on XNA-UK.NET which recently ran through a tutorial to show off all the Silverlight / XNA integration ans shows how to convert an XNA project in to an integrated project.

[XNA to SilverXNA](http://xna-uk.net/blogs/darkgenesis/archive/2011/08/21/xna-to-silverxna-part-1-an-overview.aspx)

In answer to your question, unfortunately the integration is only one way Silverlight -> XNA, you cannot access Silverlight libraries from an XNA only package.
Also currently in the Silverlight Integration you also loose the Components functionality but as shown by Shawn Hargreaves you can re-factor in a very similar functionality yourself - 
[Silverlight XNA Game Components (Mango, C#/VB)](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/silverlight_xna_game_components)

Hope this helps

Simon